# Multiple null Checks or try/catch NullPointerException

Tags: java, null

There is A LOT of information online stating that you should NEVER catch a NullPointerException.  Generally I agree, but I am wondering about this one case.

I have inherited code that requires me to access data that I need in the following way

```
context.getGrandParent().getParent().getChild().isRequired()
```

There is no guarantee that any of the objects in this hierarchy will not be null. 
 I have to enter a block if isRequired() returns true.  First, and what I initially wrote, with null checks:

```
if(context != null
   && context.getGrandParent() != null
   && context.getGrandParent().getParent() != null
   && context.getGrandParent().getParent().getChild() != null 
   && context.getGrandParent().getParent().getChild().isRequired()
){
   // continue with business logic
} else {
   LOG.error("Unable to determine if processing is required.");
}    
// continue with other inherited code
```

Setting aside that I could refactor this, perhaps for readability, wouldn't it make more sense to do the following?

```
boolean isRequired = false;
try {
   isRequired = context.getGrandParent().getParent().getChild().isRequired();
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
   LOG.error("Unable to determine if processing is required.");
}

if(isRequired){
   // continue with business logic
}
// continue with other inherited code
```

Comment: some notes on null propagation: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: yes i like the version with an exception. You should not make a code where  normal funtionality is that some variable is present or not. You sould not make if-else branches instead of exception cases ( like in AJNeufeld answer) in error log howewer you must determine what exactly place is absent)

Comment: I agree, use the exception, guidelines are for the obedience of fools and the guidance of wise men.  This is a case were clarity reigns.

Comment: @dfhwze: Thanks for the link.  It gives a good overview of Optional that AJNeufeld recommends.

Comment: `.getParent().getChild()` wait what? Doesn't that go back to where we came from?

Comment: The real solution here is not to catch a null-pointer or use an `Optional`, you should find a way to inject the value of `context.getGrandParent().getParent().getChild()` as a separate variable/field, or inject a `Predicate` where you inject `childYouAreLookingFor.isRequired()`. Your current code goes against the principle of "Tell, don't ask"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with catching `NullPointerException` is “which one did you catch?”  A `null` can be returned from `getGrandParent()`, and using that return value without checking will cause the exception.  **OR** a bug in `getGrandParent()` might cause an exception while trying to find the parent’s parent, and you are obscuring the bug by assuming the `NullPointerException` results from a properly returned `null` value.

You can use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) to properly capture the `null` and not call subsequent function.

```
Optional<Boolean> isRequired = Optional.ofNullable(context)
                          .map(Context::getGrandParent)
                          .map(GrandParent::getParent)
                          .map(Parent::getChild)
                          .map(Child::isRequired);

if (!isRequired.isPresent()) {
    LOG.error("Unable to determine if processing is required.");
} else if (isRequired.get()) {
    // continue with business logic
}
```

The `Context::`, `GrandParent::`, `Parent::`, `Child::` class types are, of course, WAG's.  You'll need to supply the corrent types based on the type returned by the previous stage.

Alternately, you could use `.getOrElse(Boolean.FALSE)` at the end of the `.map()` chain.

Comment: This may be the only case where creating an Optional to avoid an explicit null check would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I think I will go this route.  For academic reasons, would you have the same opinion if all of the getters are actually just getters with no logic?  In that case there would be no bug (it would just return a reference to a member or null).

Comment: @TCCV Absolutely.  For what might be a getter with no logic today may become a computation or delegation method tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of @AJNeufeld is elegant and solves your immediate problem. However, I want to make a case for doing things the verbose way: check for each bad condition individually, log an error if the value is null, and continue onward otherwise. This has two advantages.

First, it allows custom error messages depending on which value is null. If a missing field is a serious error in your data, your error log should have tons of information about it! Simply giving up and logging a generic error does not help you fix the database.

Second, it allows you to assign each object to a variable. Presumably, you need to use at least some of these objects inside of the business logic, so having variables bound to each will avoid extra calls to the getters later on.

The resulting code would look something like this.

```
if (context == null) {
    LOG.error("Cannot process: context is null.");
    return;
}

GrandParent grandParent = context.getGrandParent();
if (grandParent == null) {
    LOG.error(String.format("Cannot process: context %s has null grandParent.", context));
    return;
}

Parent parent = grandParent.getParent();
if (parent == null) {
    LOG.error(String.format("Cannot process: grandParent %s has null parent.", grandParent));
    return;
}

Child child = parent.getChild();
if (child == null) {
    LOG.error(String.format("Cannot process: parent %s has null child.", parent));
    return;
}

if (child.isRequired()) {
    // business logic
}
```

The code is admittedly quite verbose, but it is readable and clear. In production, useful error messages like these can be much more important than concise code.

Comment: It also avoids a possible concurrent execution logic problem in the second code block of the OP's post, where `context.getGrandParent() != null` evaluates to `true`, but by the time `&& context.getGrandParent().getParent() != null` is evaluated, `getGrandParent()` now returns a `null` and results in the `NullPointerException` anyway.  Keeping each object, as it is retrieved, in a local variable prevents the item you just tested from changing just after you tested it.